# Plotted map shown small on Plots panel

Tags: r, plot, shapefile, geopackage

I'm trying to plot a map for New-Zealand, with data taken from [here](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html). It's a geopackage of New-Zealand from gadm.

I'm currently selecting the first layer, and thought it was a projection problem so I reprojected to EPSG 4167, this is the New Zealand Geodetic Datum 2000.

```
zealand <- read_sf("NZL.gpkg", "gadm36_NZL_0") 
st_crs(zealand)<- "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"
zealand<- zealand%>% st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
```

How can I get a zoomed in image?

Here's the plot:
[image]